# Similarity of triangles, theory 4, proof

Tags: proof-writing, triangles

On most of the internet sides I have read just 3 triangle similarity theorems, but I found out, there is also a 4: "Two triangles are similar if the lengths of two corresponding sides are proportional and their corresponding angles across the larger of these two are congruent."

I tried to find a proof for it, but I didnt find anything. I am very interested in it, I remember in high school, we studied similarity, but rarely proved anything.

Comment: You can find a proof [here](https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-cbse-math-class-10/section/6.6/primary/lesson/sas-triangle-similarity/).

Comment: @BeKind I am confused by the posting, and confused by the need for a proof.  I thought that if all three angles in one triangle were equal to the three angles in the 2nd triangle, then the triangles were automatically regarded as *similar*.  It has been specified that two of the angles are equal (i.e. congruent).  This automatically implies that the 3rd angles in each triangle are also equal, which then implies that the triangles must be similar.  This means that the specification re the lengths of various sides of the triangles is redundant.  Have I misunderstood/misinterpreted the situation?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but no, it is not the proof what I am looking for. The SAS proof is an another thing. Here we know that the lengths of two corresponding sides are proportional, and the corresponding angle of the larger of those two are congruent. So we have just one congruent angle, not two! In front of the larger side, we have that one angle.

Comment: https://mathemania.com/lesson/triangle-similarity/amp/

Comment: @Holdviola Which one do you mean then? The SSA theorem?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the name of it

Comment: I just wrote the link where I found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof of the SSA theorem:

Suppose you know the lengths of 2 sides of a triangle and the angle of the smaller side that is not between the 2 known sides. Without loss of generality, let the shorter side be AB and longer side be BD, with the angle extending from point A. Then, you should have a construction akin to this:

[image: AB is the known shorter side. BC is the longer side with known length.]

We already know the lengths of AB (shorter side) and BD (longer side). The circle with center B and radius BC is the set of all possible points satisfying the length condition of BD. Also, the known angle is $\angle BAB'$ here. Ray $\overrightarrow{AB'}$ denotes the set of all possible points satisfying the angle condition. There is only one intersection, therefore, there only exists one unique point D. This means only one unique triangle that satisfies both conditions.

Hence, if 2 triangles have the same SSA, they must be congruent. QED.

Extra: If you wonder why this fails when the angle is next to the smaller side, consider this figure:

[image: Now BC is greater than AB]

There are now 2 intersections, meaning 2 noncongruent triangles satisfy the same conditions, so 2 triangles having the same SSA need not mean they are congruent.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I have to think about  a little bit, but i think I will be fine.